# Medium-Style page transition and Parallax

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition, parallax

I'm making a website using Medium-Style page transition and Parallax (Stellar.js) on those main images (top and bottom).

Everything is working fine but there's a problem when clicking on the bottom image to change the article, here parallax effect is only working on the one of the top, the other one just stops working and if click again to get back to the first article now both stop working.

Steps:

1- Parallax is working fine on both images (top and bottom)
2- When clicking the last image to change the article Parallax stops working on the bottom image but keep working on first one
3- If click again on the last image to change to the first article Parallax stops working on both images

I would like to solve this to always have the Parallax effect.

For being honest can't find a solution and couldn't find it around.

Here's a like to the website: http://hidden-workshop.com/newProject/#1

Thanks a lot and any doubt please ask me.